Parent process completing before child but still prints out data from pipe
I recreated the example in the man pages for the pipe() system call and am a little confused as to why the 'Hello world' message is printed when the parent process seems to complete before the child process:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  const int BSIZE = 100;
  int fildes[2];
  char buff[BSIZE];

  pipe(fildes);
  pid_t rc = fork();

  if (rc == 0) {
    printf("in child\n");
    close(fildes[0]);
    write(fildes[1], "Hello world\n", 13);
    close(fildes[1]);
  } else {
    printf("in parent\n");
    close(fildes[1]);
    read(fildes[0], buff, BSIZE);
    close(fildes[0]);
    printf("%s", buff);
  }

  return 0;
}

The output from this looks like:
in parent
in child
Hello world

From the output it looks like the parent process is finishing before the child process runs. If so, how does Hello world print? If read is called before the child process finishes writing i would expect buff to be empty (or at least incomplete) when read is called.
I to remove the close() calls to see if read() was waiting on the other end to close or if the pipe() method waited, but I got the same results.
Is this just a timing thing? It just happens to finish this way and I should be adding a `wait()` call in the parent process?
I didn't the answer in the man page for pipe(), and couldn't phrase it properly for google, so I thought I would try and ask here.
Thanks

From the output it looks like the parent process is finishing before the child process runs. What in the output tells you this?

The two processes are running at the same time. So output you see from the two processes may overlap.

Your code is incomplete without headers, and you don't declare the variable rc so you never executed what you posted.

The child process doesn't do any printing to stdout.

@AndrewHenle Output to stdout is the very first thing the child does.

@tkausl the order of the print statements made it seem that way to me. When adding a print statements at the end of each process (i.e. printf("out child")) i can see that the parent does not finish first

@Dúthomhas Yes.  I should have posted that the child doesn't write Hello World to stdout.

@AndrewHenle Heh, no worries, words come out of my fingertips the wrong way all the time. I think it’s because I’m getting old.
